# asp.net MVC and Silverlight data communication through a web service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, silverlight-3.0

I am having a bit of trouble getting started with connecting my MVC app with some sprinkled in silverlight to a web service to interface the two with a database...

Currently I have my linq to sql class living in my models in my MVC but I want to be able to hit it in the service from both my silverlight application and my MVC stuff so I don't have to maintain two linq to sql classes. The problem is I have some partial classes in my MVC to add some validation logic onto the LINQ table classes and I had some troubles with those not working when I moved my LINQ-to-SQL class out of that project into the service.

Does anyone know of some good jumping off points or some good tutorials out there for silverlight 3 and web services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good tutorial at http://silverlight.net/learn/tutorials/sqldatagrid-cs/ if anyone else runs into this problem

Comment: took a lot of googling but found this page too http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd939784.aspx